# Algorithms runtime when array is doubled

Tags: algorithm

I ran a few tests to see which array performed the fastest on different random array sizes.  Originally the maximin array was 50,000. I then increased it to 100,000.  I had expected that to calculate the original 50,000 in both runs would be the same but there is a huge difference for some of the sort methods.  Any ideas on why this would be?
[image: max 50,000 array]

[image: max 100,000 array]

Comment: What  should we see at these pictures? You would to explain your test methodics.

Comment: Your data is highly suspect. In both runs, your two largest sizes ran at almost the same speed for bubble sort and insertion sort. That suggests you're doing something wrong. If you want to make a question of this that won't be closed, you need to give more details about how you're generating the test data and how you're measuring the results.

Comment: Hypothesis: the last row of your data (row 13 in the first, row 14 in the second) in both cases is bogus.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I am new to this and just trying to figure it out.  I created a randomly generated array and was playing around with it to try and understand it better.  It did strike me as odd that the run times for the larger sizes were almost the same. Hence my question.